# [Bash]: Handling many signals

Tags: linux, bash, shell, signals

I'm playing with bash and signal handlers and found one interesting thing. But I can't explain why it so.

For example, we have a script test.sh which do something and can handle SIGTERM:

```
trap 'echo "sig 15 rcvd" ' 15
trap 'echo "sig 10 rcvd" ' 10
while true
do
    ; do something
    sleep 0.2
done
```

So, when I sent a few signals to this script:

```
kill -15 <pidof test.sh>; kill -10 <pidof test.sh>
```

I've got signal 10 received early than signal 15:

```
sig 10 rcvd
sig 15 rcvd
```

If I send 2 times signal 10 or 15 script printed only once it:

```
kill -15 <pidof test.sh>; kill -15 <pidof test.sh>
sig 15 rcvd
```

It's also strange: I suggest that it's because we have double signal to the same pid and only one signal will be sent to it. Or there are some other reasons for this behavior?

And the last interesting thing: Remove sleep from script and send a both signals:

```
test.sh 
trap 'echo "sig 15 rcvd" ' 15
trap 'echo "sig 10 rcvd" ' 10
while true
do
    ; do something
done
```

and send some signals to this script:

```
kill -10 <pidof test.sh>; kill -15 <pidof test.sh>;\
kill -10 <pidof test.sh>; kill -10 <pidof test.sh>;\
kill -15 <pidof test.sh>;
```

I've got unexpected results:

```
sig 10 rcvd
sig 10 rcvd
sig 15 rcvd
sig 10 rcvd
sig 10 rcvd
```

So, could someone describe why this happened? Why bash(?) mix up signals/remove one signals and add additional others??

UPD: One more interesting thing. Script looks like:

```
trap 'echo "sig 15 rcvd"; exit ' 15
trap 'echo "EXIT"' EXIT
```

After kill -15  I have "sig 15 rcvd" and "EXIT".
But if I send kill -15 two times EXIT handler doesn't executed:

```
sig 15 rcvd
sig 15 rcvd
```

Comment: This is interesting. Could you try replacing `;` with `&&` and seeing what kind of output you get? It is supposed to execute statement2 only after statement1 is successful.

Comment: Heh, one more unexpected result: I've got sig 10; sig 15; sig 10; sig 10 and that's it. last sig 15 is not handled :)

Comment: This is just a guess I'm not entirely sure on this but here is my two cents:
kill is also a shell builtin (well bash for sure) so when you run kill without path it is possible that the shell will use the internal kill and in doing so it may optimize if the same signal is sent repeatedly.
The actuall kill binary executable  (probabbly in /bin/kill for most systems) sends a signal so the kernel will pick it up and notify the receiving process ... the in it's own could account for the signals arriving in different order than what you might expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basic confusion is because you are expecting synchronous results from an asynchronous mechanism.

> So, when I sent a few signals to this script:
>
> ```
> kill -15 <pidof test.sh>; kill -10 <pidof test.sh>
> ```
>
> I've got signal 10 received early than signal 15:
>
> ```
> sig 10 rcvd 
> sig 15 rcvd
> ```

Those signals aren't queued. You send the first one and it begins executing the signal 15 trap but then before it completes you immediately send signal 10. This second signal interrupts the execution of the first trap. Now it executes the second trap printing `sig 10 rcvd`. When the second handler finishes it then resumes the first interrupted handler and prints `sig 15 rcvd`.

> If I send 2 times signal 10 or 15 script printed only once it:
>
> ```
> kill -15 <pidof test.sh>; kill -15 <pidof test.sh>
> sig 15 rcvd
> ```

Signals are always temporarily ignored while their signal handler is executing. If any duplicate signals are received before the trap finishes then they will not be handled. This is standard posix signal handling behavior.

It should be evident how a combination of those two behaviors can explain why you wont be able to easily predict the order of the output in your other tests.